# Hash (Multihash?) Indexing (Perl)

Tags: perl, hash, nlp, tagging

I have a function that counts frequencies of Trigrams in text. No knowledge of Computational Linguistics required, I just need help with Perl code.

This is the Function:

```
sub extract_frequencies {
    for( my $i=0; $i<=$#tag; $i++ ) {
       $wordtagfreq{"$word[$i]\t$tag[$i]"}++;
       $tagfreq{$tag[$i]}++;
    }

    # count Tag-Trigramm-Frequencies
    my @start = ("<s>","<s>");
    unshift @tag, @start;  # korrigiert
    push @tag, "<s>";
    for( my $i=2; $i<=$#tag; $i++ ) {
        $ngramfreq[3]{"$tag[$i-2]\t$tag[$i-1]\t$tag[$i]"}++;
    }
 }
```

The particular code points that I do not understand are the following:

1) `$ngramfreq`[3]

What does the Index on the hash means here? Do I count for each Tag separately? Is it the length of the key? What is my end key (3 different tag keys?)?

2) `$i<=$#tag`

What does `$#` in Perl mean?

Haven't used Perl in a while, so I hope some Perl Monks will help me.

Comment: You might want to check array of hashes http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#ARRAYS-OF-HASHES and http://perlmaven.com/perl-arrays respectively.

Comment: I would add `use Data::Dumper;` to the beginning of your script and `print Dumper \@ngramfreq` to see your data structure

Comment: If you want answers form Perl Monks, go to http://www.perlmonks.org :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[0]` is an array index, nothing to do with a hash. This implies that `ngramfreq` is actually an array of hashes:

```
my @ngramfreq = (
                     { tag => 1, fish => 3 },
                     { anothertag => 4 } 
                );
```

And thus `$ngramfreq[0]` gets you the first anon hash, and then you can access the tag.

`$#tag` is the last index in the array `@tag`. So with 3 elements, it would be 2, because the array indicies are 0,1,2

`Data::Dumper` is a good way of visualising a structure, to give you an idea of how it's layed out.

[`perldoc perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) is worth a read, as it expands on data structures.